# Converting mssql datetime2 to mysql datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm copying data from mssql to php variable and need to save it to mysql.

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php

    //MSSql code
    $serverName = "exserver"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"IPD", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"read");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    $tsql = "SELECT rs_date from inc";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  

    //SQL Conn
    $host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
    $user = "root"; /* User */
    $password = ""; /* Password */
    $dbname = "edge_dashboard"; /* Database name */

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$con) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
        $d= $row["0"]; 

        //sql code
        $sql = "INSERT INTO critical_sr (sr_lg_dt) VALUES ('$d')";

        if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        $con->close();
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I even tried the below:

```
$d= $row["0"];
$sub_dat =$d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO critical_sr (sr_lg_dt) VALUES ('$sub_dat')";
```

I always encounter this error "Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in".

The datatype of `row["0"]` in MSSQL is `datetime2`. I need it to be saved in datetime format in MySQL.

Comment: Missing `"` on this line `$tsql = "SELECT rs_date from inc;`

Comment: `$d` is a string. It does not have a format method. Use DateTime object if you want to do that

Comment: `$row["1"]` does not exists `$d= $row[0];` might exist if you fix the TYPO of the missing double quote. You only have one column selected in the query and arrays start at Zero in PHP

Comment: You may also get issues as `datetime2` uses 7 places for the seconds fraction and MySQL uses only 6. You may need to chop a character off or pass the date2 through a reformat process

Comment: There are just to many errors and ommissions in this code

Comment: You are also connecting to MySQL ONCE EVERYTIME ROUND THE WHILE LOOP. That is unnecessary and will slow this script unnecessarily

Comment: **Ah and most importantly** you dont seem to have made a connection to the SQLServer database anywhere in this code !!!!

Comment: Hey, I fixed the code. Please recheck.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors. **To see your next error reported**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. The solution was simple. I changed the code as below.

$date = $row["0"];
    $result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

I had set DateTime size as 6 in MySQL which added unwanted precisions when inserting.  I removed the size and it works fine now. No error. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
$sDat =$d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

to create a string-variable and use ti in your insert-statement with

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO critical_sr (sr_lg_dt) VALUES ('$sDat')";
```

Comment: `$d` is a string, so it doesn't have `format`. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: Only if `$sDat` is first instantiated as a DateTime Object. And you and the OP have not done that